# How to add sorting option to a field in views bulk operation

Tags: views

I have created one view with the help of views bulk operations and now I want one of the field to able to sort records according to the field value.

I am attaching image[image]

How can I make the "credits" field as sorting field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with VBO. It is simply a setting in the "Table" format. To achieve this:

1. Click "Settings" besides "Table" format.
   [image: snap]
2. And select which field you need to make sortable.
   [image: snap]

Comment: I am using Drupal 6

Comment: Hey It is there in Drupal 6 Also.Its a correct answer..!

Comment: @Akki Glad it helped!

Comment: I am having another problem, Credit field is numeric and when I sort by clicking on this credit field, it is not working correctly